# Use Azure data sync with localdb

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, localdb, data-synchronization, azure-data-sync

B"H

How can I use Azure Data Sync with **localdb**?

Please note: I am not asking about using it with a "Local Database" as in an on-prem database. I am speaking specifically about the technology (particular Sql Server Edition) known as **localdb**. As in `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`.

The issue is adding the `localdb` instance to `SQL Data Sync Agent`. The agent must be run under an entity (windows login) that has permission to run as a service. **It can not be run using a windows live identity** which is what the users are usually logged in as. Yet it also needs to have permissions to the database in localdb.

Use Case:

I have a central database running in Azure. With multiple users with laptops and limited internet connection, running local apps (some built in Access). Connecting directly from the apps to Azure is too slow or otherwise impractical. Therefore I install the lightweight `localdb` as a cache for the users data. Which will be merged using Azure Data Sync.

I am currently using a solution built directly on Microsoft Sync *Framework*. However there is a maintenance overhead on that solution. So I would like to migrate to the Microsoft maintained Azure Data Sync.

Thank you

Comment: Why not use SQL Server Express?

Comment: Because it is *much* heavier, needs to be installed separately, is constantly running in the background and taking up lots of resources (not only when you're using this app). These are the reasons that Microsoft created localdb. They literally created this  edition specifically for this scenario. So I'd like to continue using it for all those benefits.

Comment: @ErikEJ Doing a quick search. I see that you are the one always explaining to everyone else what the difference is between Express and LocalDb and when and why you'd use each. Why did you change your tune for my scenario?

Comment: maybe you should take a look at https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync

Comment: Thank you! Looks like you have a great product there. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

B"H

Ok, it was actually a silly mistake.

You actually **can** run the `SQL Data Sync Agent` using a windows live identity. You just need to use the local user name. Which is the name of the folder for that user in the `Users` folder. You must also use the name of the computer in the format `MyComputer\localUserName`.
Once I was running the `SQL Data Sync Agent` under the currently logged in user - who also has access to the DB - everything else ran smoothly.